# Printing results without spaces python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
def WhichAreCaps(Word):
    for w in Word:
        if w.isupper() == True:
          print (w)

WhichAreCaps("IJkdLenMd")
```

Result:

```
I
J
L
M
```

So I'm trying to build a code that finds Capitalized letters in a string and print out the letters. The problem is that I want the result to come out as one line of string, not four. Is there a way to do so? (I'm just a beginner;;)

Comment: You `''.join(..)` the characters together...

Comment: See the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation (especially the `end` argument).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've tries doing print (" ".join(w)), still the same probelm

Comment: BTW, your function would be more useful if it returns the results as a string instead of printing them. That way, the caller could print the results themself, or do some other processing on the results before printing them.

Comment: @ChikkinMan Change approach: `"".join(c for c in word if c.isupper())`.

Comment: You _could_ do this: `print(''.join(filter(str.isupper, word)))`, but you probably shouldn't. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring How would it look like if it was returned? I have a hard time converting print() to return()

Comment: Well, you put a `return` statement at the end of the function, once you've finished the processing and have collected the results into a list or string. Eg, you can change the last line of [Akshay Apte's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42857468/4014959) from `print(ans)` to `return ans`. And then you could call it like `print(WhichAreCaps("IJkdLenMd"))`. Or doing it on separate lines `s = WhichAreCaps("IJkdLenMd")`  `print(s)`. That way you can do other stuff with `s`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh thank you, I didn't know the check mark thingy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` function accepts an `end` keyword argument to specifies the end of the string after printing. By default it's set to new line (`\n`), you can simply use a space. Also note that checking the truths value of any expression with `== True` is wrong since `True` interprets as 1 and every thing that returns 1 will be interpreted as True. You can simply use `if w.isupper()`:

```
def WhichAreCaps(Word):
    for w in Word:
        if w.isupper():
          print(w, end=' ')
```

Another way is `yield`ing the vowels in your function and make it a generator:

```
def WhichAreCaps(Word):
    for w in Word:
        if w.isupper():
            yield w
```

Then you can join the result in any way you like and print it:

```
print(','.join(WhichAreCaps(Word)))
```

After all, as a more pythonic approach for this ask you can simply use a list comprehension within `str.join`:

```
print(' '.join([w for w in Word if w.isupper()]))
```

Comment: I would clean it up with an empty `print()` just before i `return`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks would be good to.

Comment: @Kasramvd Yup, used the end=" " and it worked.! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can Just append the letters to an empty string and then return it.

```
def WhichAreCaps(Word):
    ans=''
    for w in Word:
        if w.isupper() == True:
          ans+=w
    print(ans)
```

Comment: I do not understand the dv.. Can the downvoter explain?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Maybe it's because it's a code-only answer. Or maybe the down-voter voted on the early version of the answer which used the Python 2 `print` statement and didn't notice that Akshay fixed that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm relatively new to SO.

Comment: I downvoted because 1) it's a code only answer, 2) `== True` is redundant, and mostly 3) I don't condone string concatenation because it's underperformant.